# Generating 30 minutes time slots going into next day using moment.js

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, moment-timezone

```
var x = {
    next-slot: 30,
    start-time: '21:00',
    end-time: '05:00'
}
```

**I want to generate time slots , starting from start Time till end Time. Output should be**

```
[21:00, 21:30, 22:00, 22:30, 23:00, 23:30, 00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, 02:00, 02:30, 03:00, 03:30, 04:00, 04:30]
```

I am doing below logic Its working for (Below Date range)
start-time: '05:00',
end-time: '21:00'
Not Working For : (Below Date range)
start-time: '21:00',
end-time: '05:00'

```
const hours = [];
          for (
            let hour = Number(start-time[0]);
            hour <= Number(end-time[0]);
            hour++
          ) {
              hours.push(moment({ hour }).format('kk:mm'));
              hours.push(
                moment({
                  hour,
                  minute: 30,
                }).format('kk:mm')
              );
          }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276306/display-time-duration-based-on-start-and-end-date-with-interval-using-moment-js

Comment: Hi Chellappan, I need time slots from these rage: start-time: '21:00', end-time: '05:00'

[21:00, 21:30, 22:00, 22:30, 23:00, 23:30, 00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, 02:00, 02:30, 03:00, 03:30, 04:00, 04:30]

Comment: The above link you shared that is not work for my Criteria. Please help me out..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what you need. To get the time you will use format as `HH:mm` for start time in data.

The `end time` you have is in the `next` day so we need to use `moment.js` [add()](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/01-add/) function which we will use to add `1` day to end time.

Next while loping over the time we will set interval from our `data` which is set to `30` in `moment.js` minutes

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
//Data
let x = {
  slotInterval: 30,
  openTime: '21:00',
  closeTime: '05:00'
};

//Format the time
let startTime = moment(x.openTime, "HH:mm");

//Format the end time and the next day to it 
let endTime = moment(x.closeTime, "HH:mm").add(1, 'days');

//Times
let allTimes = [];

//Loop over the times - only pushes time with 30 minutes interval
while (startTime < endTime) {
  //Push times
  allTimes.push(startTime.format("HH:mm")); 
  //Add interval of 30 minutes
  startTime.add(x.slotInterval, 'minutes');
}

console.log(allTimes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For anyone using dayjs, remember to do startTime = startTime.add(30, 'minutes') because dayjs.add() doesn't mutate.

Comment: @Edwin if i read your comment i dont need to spend hour just to figure out how to make it work with dayjs.